# Как убрать NaN при пустом значении input в калькуляторе

Tags: javascript, битрикс

```
<?php if ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['cof']['VALUE'] != "") { ?>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card__line mt-2 mb-3"></div>
            <div class="calc-inner-block">
                <div class="calc-input__wpr">
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" id="tons" value="" oninput="calc()" /><span style="position: absolute;margin: 8px 0px 0px -28px;"></span>
                    <span class="calc-input__text" style="font-size: 14px;cursor: pointer;">тонны</span>
                </div>
                <div class="calc-input__wpr" style="border-left: 1px solid #9E9E9E;">
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" id="result" value="" oninput="calc2()" /><span style="position: absolute;margin: 8px 0px 0px -28px;"></span>
                    <span class="calc-input__text" style="font-size: 14px;cursor: pointer;">метры</span>
                </div>
                <input style="visibility: hidden;position: absolute;" type="text" id="coef"
                       value="<?= $arResult['PROPERTIES']['cof']['VALUE'] ?>" oninput="calc()" oninput="calc2()"/>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function calc() {

                    var tons = document.getElementById("tons");
                    var coef = document.getElementById("coef");

                    var result = document.getElementById("result");

                    var sum = 0;

                    sum = parseFloat(tons.value) * parseFloat(coef.value);

                    result.value = sum.toFixed(4);

                }

                function calc2() {

                    var tons = document.getElementById("tons");
                    var coef = document.getElementById("coef");

                    var result = document.getElementById("result");

                    var sum = 0;

                    sum = parseFloat(result.value) / parseFloat(coef.value);

                    tons.value = sum.toFixed(4);

                }

            </script>


        </div>
        <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверить, пустое значение или нет, перед тем как выполнять вычисления.

```js
function calc() {
    var tons = document.getElementById("tons");
    var coef = document.getElementById("coef");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
   
    var sum = 0;
    if(tons.value != ""){
        sum = parseFloat(tons.value) * parseFloat(coef.value);
    }
    result.value = sum.toFixed(4);
}

function calc2() {
    var tons = document.getElementById("tons");
    var coef = document.getElementById("coef");
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    var sum = 0;
    if(result.value != ""){
        sum = parseFloat(result.value) / parseFloat(coef.value);
    }
    tons.value = sum.toFixed(4);                
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="" type="text" id="coef" value="1" />

<div class="d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="card__line mt-2 mb-3"></div>
    <div class="calc-inner-block">
        <div class="calc-input__wpr">
            <input placeholder="" type="text" id="tons" value="" oninput="calc()" />
            <span style="position: absolute;margin: 8px 0px 0px -28px;"></span>
            <span class="calc-input__text" style="font-size: 14px;cursor: pointer;">тонны</span>
        </div>
        <div class="calc-input__wpr" style="border-left: 1px solid #9E9E9E;">
            <input placeholder="" type="text" id="result" value="" oninput="calc2()" />
            <span style="position: absolute;margin: 8px 0px 0px -28px;"></span>
            <span class="calc-input__text" style="font-size: 14px;cursor: pointer;">метры</span>
        </div>
        <input style="visibility: hidden;position: absolute;" type="text" id="coef" value="" oninput="calc()" oninput="calc2()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```